# How to Invalidate previous login session

Tags: spring, session

I'm facing some security issue

I have two jsp pages(login page and after login) and I'm exploring them on Chrome.

After I login, the browser moves the page.

Then, if I press the back button on browser tab, the browser moves back to login page. However, The session from my previous login is still valid. 
So, I can explore entire web freely by just removing '/login' from my url

What I have to do is..
if the browser moves back to login page, I should invalidate previous session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login page you can check if `session` is set or not always like below :

```
 <% if(session.getAttribute("user")!=null){ 
               response.sendRedirect("your profile page");//redirect to some page
                }
  %>
```

In above code,if `user` is not null ,then it will go to your `profile-page` ,put this code in your `login.jsp` to prevent user to login again ,also don't forget to `set` your Attribute i.e : user

Comment: I tried it on firefox, if you use your browsers back function, the `<% %>` expression will not be executed (checked the server logs), probably because the browser loads it from its cache.